# Executing an external script via Javascript rather than <script src="external.aspx">

Tags: javascript

**1) Here is what works just fine:**

SearchTool.aspx (in the code snippet below) is a 3rd party product that will actually insert an iframe into the page at page load time with the search tool inside of it.

```
<html>
<head>....</head>
<body>
...
...
<h2>Search Tool</h2>
<script type='' src='http://foo.com/SearchTool.aspx</script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**2) Here is what I want to do:**

I want my page to load quickly without the search tool being loaded at the same time. The user can read through my page and then, if they want, they can click on a button to load the search tool thereby delaying the tool load time to when they want it.

I want to be able to invoke the SearchTool.aspx from the click of a button as below, but I don't know what the code would look like in the showSearch() function below:

```
<h2>Search Tool</h2>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showSearch(){

**** What would go here? *****

}
</script>

<input .....="" onclick="showSearch();"></input>
```

**3) I have already explored creating the iframe manually:**

In the code snippet #1 above that works just fine, if I do a view source and then create an iframe exactly like they do with all of the same properties, the Search Tool doesn't completely work properly.  Weird I know, but true. So this is NOT an option.

Comment: Can you control the output of SearchTool.aspx? You can do something like reading its content via AJAX and paste it wherever you want in the document.

Comment: simply do a document.CreateElement to create the script tag, then insert it into the Dom. Look at the google analytics code to see how it is done. They do the same thing

Comment: Rotem, I'm not familiar with AJAX so I wouldn't know if that would be possible.

Comment: Funny you should mention mimicking the google analytics code because I have already tried that and "nothing" happens.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your script tag in a div with the style `display:none` to hide it:

```
<h2>Search Tool</h2>
<div id="searchTool" style="display:none">
  <script type='' src='http://foo.com/SearchTool.aspx</script>
</div>
...
```

Then, in your function, just show it :

```
function showSearch(){
  document.getElementById("searchTool").style.display = 'block';    
}
```

Comment: Your solution still invokes the aspx at page load time which is what I want to avoid. I want the my page to load quickly without the search tool being loaded at the same time,  they can read through my page and then, if the user desires, they can click on a button to load the search tool thereby delaying the tool load time to when they want it.